# Xamarin.iOS: Need help solving crash report from Apple

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Apple rejected my app because they say it was crashing at launch and told me to test on a device (which I had already done). I cannot reproduce the crash on my end as the app is launching just fine on various devices and all simulators. I have looked at the crash report they provided but I am having trouble deciphering exactly what the problem is. Here's what it shows:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Thread 0 name:  tid_303  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000023464b104 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002346c7020 pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 380
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000002345a2e1c __abort + 152
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000002345a2d84 __abort + 0
4   MyAppName                       0x00000001026bfce8 print_callback(char const*, int) + 3226856 (runtime.m:1215)
5   MyAppName                       0x00000001026ba9a8 monoeg_g_log + 3205544 (goutput.c:125)
6   MyAppName                       0x0000000102586ab0 load_aot_module + 1944240 (aot-runtime.c:2117)
7   MyAppName                       0x00000001025d5744 mono_assembly_load_from_predicate + 2266948 (assembly.c:2455)
8   MyAppName                       0x00000001025d5284 mono_assembly_open_predicate + 2265732 (assembly.c:2028)
9   MyAppName                       0x00000001026bf544 xamarin_open_and_register + 3224900 (runtime.m:943)
10  MyAppName                       0x00000001026c5b7c xamarin_main + 3251068 (monotouch-main.m:434)
11  MyAppName                       0x00000001023b8854 main + 51284 (main.m:40)
12  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000002344febb4 start + 4
```

UPDATE:

I just got a random crash at launch in the iPad Pro simulator. Haven't been able to reproduce it again, but here's the info I got from the report when it happened. Not sure if it relates to the crash report above from Apple or not.

```
MonoTouch: Could not install sigaction override, unexpected sigaction implementation.
MyAppName[3634:224014] [ApplicationLifecycle] Windows were created before application initialzation completed. This may result in incorrect visual appearance.
MyAppName[3634:224014] RPCTimeout.mm:55:_ReportRPCTimeout: Start: Mach message timeout. Apparently deadlocked. Aborting now.

MyAppName[3634:224014] critical: Stacktrace:
MyAppName[3634:224014] critical:   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
MyAppName[3634:224014] critical:   at (wrapper managed-to-native) ObjCRuntime.Messaging.objc_msgSend (intptr,intptr,intptr,bool) [0x0000b] in <bbd12705940f4bb29392519af87b535b>:0
MyAppName[3634:224014] critical:   at SpriteKit.SKAction.PlaySoundFileNamed (string,bool) [0x00024] in <bbd12705940f4bb29392519af87b535b>:0
MyAppName[3634:224014] critical:   at MyAppName.Game.LoadSoundsIntoMemory () [0x00000] in <1d73fc98fddc46f793f1fd5f7904e89b>:0
MyAppName[3634:224014] critical:   at MyAppName.ViewController.ViewWillLayoutSubviews () [0x00046] in <1d73fc98fddc46f793f1fd5f7904e89b>:0
MyAppName[3634:224014] critical:   at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_void__this__ (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x0001e] in <2b439461a53d406abf16d6e5e34ece7f>:0
MyAppName[3634:224014] critical:   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
MyAppName[3634:224014] critical:   at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr) [0x00051] in <bbd12705940f4bb29392519af87b535b>:0
MyAppName[3634:224014] critical:   at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],intptr,intptr) [0x00005] in <bbd12705940f4bb29392519af87b535b>:0
MyAppName[3634:224014] critical:   at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],string,string) [0x0002c] in <bbd12705940f4bb29392519af87b535b>:0
MyAppName[3634:224014] critical:   at MyAppName.AppDelegate.Main (string[]) [0x00000] in <1d73fc98fddc46f793f1fd5f7904e89b>:0
MyAppName[3634:224014] critical:   at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x0004e] in <1d73fc98fddc46f793f1fd5f7904e89b>:0
MyAppName[3634:224014] critical: 

Native stacktrace:
MyAppName[3634:224014] critical:    0   MyAppName                           0x00000001034aae74 mono_handle_native_crash + 244
MyAppName[3634:224014] critical:    1   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x000000010f74bb3d _sigtramp + 29
MyAppName[3634:224014] critical:    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010f759570 libsystem_pthread.dylib + 1392
MyAppName[3634:224014] critical:    3   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x000000010f4d7c45 abort + 127
MyAppName[3634:224014] critical:    4   AudioToolbox                        0x0000000118021884 _Z17_ReportRPCTimeoutPKci + 181
MyAppName[3634:224014] critical:    5   AudioToolbox                        0x0000000117c84c3e _Z14_CheckRPCErrorPKcii + 206
MyAppName[3634:224014] critical:    6   AudioToolbox                        0x0000000117c89fb1 _ZN10AURemoteIO5StartEv + 513
MyAppName[3634:224014] critical:    7   AudioToolbox                        0x0000000118036b9d _ZL13AUMethodStartPv + 63
MyAppName[3634:224014] critical:    8   AudioToolbox                        0x0000000117e7d991 _ZN14AudioUnitGraph5StartEv + 305
MyAppName[3634:224014] critical:    9   OpenAL                              0x00000001283377e7 _ZN9OALDevice14ConnectContextEP10OALContext + 755
MyAppName[3634:224014] critical:    10  OpenAL                              0x0000000128334840 _ZN10OALContext20ConnectMixerToDeviceEv + 98
MyAppName[3634:224014] critical:    11  OpenAL                              0x00000001283385e0 alcMakeContextCurrent + 379
MyAppName[3634:224014] critical:    12  SpriteKit                           0x0000000105636182 +[SKPlaySound playSoundFileNamed:atPosition:waitForCompletion:] + 330
MyAppName[3634:224014] critical:    13  SpriteKit                           0x000000010559e69f +[SKAction(SKActions) playSoundFileNamed:waitForCompletion:] + 40
MyAppName[3634:224014] critical:    14  ???                                 0x000000012ca13ee8 0x0 + 5043732200
MyAppName[3634:224014] critical: 
=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't really work with that. Simplest solution might be to integrate a crash reporting framework (like AppCenter) before submitting. If apple testers encounter a crash you're going to receive it, in a managed .NET way, which wil lbe a lot easier for you to debug

Comment: Seems like you are submitting a debug-based build to Apple.

Comment: @SushiHangover Can you elaborate? I made sure that Release was selected when I built the archive to send to Apple.

Comment: @kryptonking Check if your app has some restrictions under debug, causing problems with the release version. For example, whether to use intranet testing, webservice data requests, etc.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Where can I find this info from within Xamarin? I've checked the iOS Build options for my project and everything seems fine there. Also checked Entitlements.plist to make sure nothing was checked (since my app doesn't need anything here) and I verified that nothing was.

Comment: @kryptonking You can first using **TestFlight** to check app what happens when running.

Comment: @kryptonking Could you please show code of AppDelegate and Main class?This will be helpful for checking where problem is.

Comment: I've resubmitted my app and it was approved. I couldn't track down the problem, but I made a few other fixes that I thought might be contributing so I guess that was it. I changed the lowest app version from 9.0 to 11.0, changed the app to be 64-bit only, and removed some spritekit audio code.